# Confusion when it comes to Two's Complement

Tags: binary, twos-complement

I'm currently trying to figure out how to do math when it comes to signed numbers. I kind of understand the concept of Two's complement, but knowing how to use it fully is what confuses me.

This is the problem I am currently dealing with:

```
1100.1111.1110-0011.1111-1010-1100.1101.1100
```

What I did was find the Two's complement of each of the numbers, and then added them together.

```
1100.1111.1110 -> 0011.0000.0010
0011.1111 -> 1100.0001
1010.1100.1101.1100 -> 0101.0011.0010.0100
```

After adding them together, I got:

```
0101.0110.1110.0111
```

I have a feeling that I messed this up, I'm just worried that I did worse than I think.

Answer (score 0):

Take 2's complement of only negative numbers and then add them with positive numbers.

One more thing, how u r getting 0011.0000.1111 as 2's complement of 1100.1111.1110, 
It should be 0011.0000.0010 &nbsp or else I didn't  get your binary representation.